# Regla Udev no funciona en Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, usb

Estoy probando un par de reglas `udev` en `Ubuntu 17.10`. Estas reglas `udev` deberían ejecutar `sendos` scripts cuando se conecte o desconecte un `pendrive`.

Las reglas `udev` son:

```
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/usbdevinserted.sh"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="unbind", RUN+="/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/usbdevgone.sh $devpath"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/usbdevgone.sh $devpath"
```

Lo he probado en anteriores versiones de `Ubuntu` y funcionan perfectamente, pero en la versión `17.10` ya no funcionan.

He instalado `udev` con:

```
sudo apt install udev
```

Y he levantado el servicio con:

```
sudo systemctl start udev
```

Pero las reglas `udev` siguen sin ejecutarse.

¿como puedo resolverlo?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Tras reiniciar el servicio con:

```
systemctl restart udev
```

ya funciona. Pero ahora resulta que, al reiniciar el sistema, se vuelve a desactivar, y tengo que volver a reiniciar el servicio para que funcionen las reglas

¿como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Te esta mostrando algun error ??

Comment: No se si muestra alguno, porque no la estoy ejecutando a mano. Simplemente, se que el script no se ejecuta, porque el fichero que debía crear no se crea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado:

Parece ser un bug de dicha versión de Ubuntu, así que, finalizamente, lo he solucionado con una tarea cron que reinicia udev al iniciarse el sistema.

Para reiniciar el servicio utilizo el comando:

```
systemctl restart udev
```